# Community ads are not displayed, but normal Stack Exchange ads are

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, advertising

It took me a while for me to notice this, but it has come to my attention that community ads are not being displayed anywhere on the main site. This issue occurs regardless of whether or not I am logged in, and regardless of the browser or device used to access the site.

The ad slot on the right side of the page displays Stack Exchange ads (such as questions elsewhere in the network) correctly, but community ads never seem to appear. Instead, I occasionally see a bugged ad slot with a blank area <s>and incorrectly displayed feedback controls</s> (*update:* the thumbs-up/thumbs-down sprites just hadn't loaded yet at the time I took the screenshot). This appears as follows in the Firefox page inspector:

[image: Bugged ad slot as seen in the Firefox page inspector]
[*View full size image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Zl7.png)

Further inspection indicates this may be an issue with the JavaScript used to load the ad.

Can someone look into this? This problem has been around for at least the last few weeks and possibly for more than a month.

Comment: do you have adblockers enabled?

Comment: @Sathya: I'm not using any ad blockers. Note that this is happening on my Android tablet as well.

Comment: Reproduced. Not sure where to start digging on this one, but I'll see if someone else knows.

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!

Where we are right now:
The open source community ads are serving just fine-- you just may not be seeing them. Reporting on our side supports that. Furthermore, the open source community ads do not have the option to upvote or downvote, but the affected creative clearly does.

At this point we're communicating with our ad server to pinpoint precisely what is going on. Relevant updates will be posted here.

---

Update: 
Adzerk tracked down the culprit and it is now off. After some poking around on SU I can't seem to find that lost div anymore, so I'm marking this issue as resolved. If you come across it again, please let us know here.

Thank you again for pointing this out!

Comment: Odd--I haven't seen any community ads in that ad slot, though. Maybe Adzerk would know more about this issue?

Comment: @DragonLord They are being shown, just not necessarily very frequently relative to other ad types. Example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7KhG1.png

Comment: Is this the same thing? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8869/is-something-wrong-with-the-way-the-ads-are-being-chosen-all-i-see-are-hot-ques